# My Dropdown in my jsp file doesn't work no matter what i try :/

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, jakarta-ee

i'm sorry to bother you with a silly problem, but i've been learning jee lately and started using bootstrap as i've been told is a nice tool, anyway i'm making a simple jsp page with a form but i noticed whenever i try to use a dropdown it doesn't work !

i don't know what i'm missing, i'd very much appreciate if someone can take a look at my code and tell what's wrong :D (i made it as simple as it can be on button in the page to find where the problem is )

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" 
        pageEncoding="UTF-8" session="false"/>
    <jsp:output doctype-root-element="html"
        doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
        omit-xml-declaration="true" />
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Bootstrap/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Bootstrap/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Bootstrap/js/Bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html> 
</jsp:root>
```

I think my problem is that i'm missing the inclusion of some sort of file or somthing but i can't tell what is it, you can see i've tried including random ones to test but nothing :'(, i have the feeling it's something really stupid but i'd very much appreciate it if someone can help me please !

Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this (see also [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_dropdown.asp)):

`<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
    });
</script>`

Comment: Hello, 

Thanks for the quick answer, i just tried it and it doesn't seem to work, when i inspected the element in the console, i had this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Ideas ?

Comment: fixed the problem with adding "<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>"
, but the main problem is still here : dropdown not working

Comment: Try to put all the scripts (bootstrap.min.js, etc...) into your `<head>` tag

Comment: when i try to put a <script></script> into the head tag and i go to the web browser i get a blank , it's as weird as it sounds :/ 

please help x)


Also i've noticed that my dropdown is working in the eclipse internal browser but not on my browser Torch neither on IE

Answer (score 0):

You can use "select instead of ul" tag without "dropdown-menu".  and "option instead of li".

Comment: thanks for the answer buddy, but i still face the same problem doesn't work :/ any other ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the inclusion of your files.

I tried your dropdown, it works as it. I think your paths are not right because you said that:

> fixed the problem with adding "<>script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">"

But jQuery is required by Bootstrap and already provided at the end ! So you missed this part at least.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Bootstrap/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Bootstrap/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Furthermore you don't need jquery.js and jquery.min.js AND js/jquery.js

.min files are minified files. They do exactly the same job. And include three or four times a file is useless.

I advice you to use the tag `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` in order to have the absolute path of your files. For example, if my app is called mywebapp on my server then `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/Bootstrap.css` will give me `/mywebapp/css/Boostrap.css`

I hope it will help.

EDIT: Is it normal that your HTML file start with an XML tag ?

Answer (score -2):

Please add in head otherwise It will not work